# Animating in Android without OPENGL

Tags: java, android, animation, graphics

I am trying to carry out basic animation in android such as rotating vectors in coordinate axis, radars etc. Two methods I encountered are:

```
    1. OPENGL ES: Its is rather heavy and I want simpler. This will also 
make the app slower as there are other operations that need to be 
carried out too.

    2. Animating different images using Animate in Android: This is easy 
but not that powerful.
```

Are there other alternative methods.

Comment: Where did you find this? From a book?

Answer (score 1):

there are lots of different ways to animate in android. 
Here's a pretty good [link](http://hiqes.com/android-animations-pt1/) detailing each type.